# Jboss 7.1.1 Cluster of three nodes

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, load-balancing

I want to create a cluster of 3 Jboss AS7 nodes and have the following scenario.

My three machines are 
1- Windows Server 2003 machine (IP: 193.16.1.146)
2- Window 7 machine (IP: 193.16.1.67)
3- Ubuntu Linux Machine (IP: 193.16.1.68)

I am using standalon-full-ha.xml configuration file to run Jboss.

The configuration file is Identical on the three machines (except the IPs) and here is the changes I have made on the three files

1- the jgroup subsystem

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" ***default-stack="tcp"***>
        <stack name="udp">
            .........
        </stack>
        <stack name="tcp">
            <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp" diagnostics-socket-binding="jgroups-diagnostics"/>
    <protocol type="TCPPING">
                <property name="initial_hosts">193.16.1.146[7600],193.16.1.68[7600],193.16.1.67[7600]</property>
                <property name="num_initial_members">3</property>
                <property name="port_range">0</property>
                <property name="timeout">2000</property>
            </protocol>
            .......
        </stack>
    </subsystem>
```

2- The interfaces

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:193.16.1.68}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:193.16.1.68}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:193.16.1.68}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

of course the IP changes from machine to machine.

Now when I form a cluster between the two windows machines, every thing works properly. when I start the two nodes I could see in the console logs (in the two machines) the connection to the other node.

When I form a cluster between the Ubuntu machine and any of the two windows machines, the ubuntu machine does not connect to the other node (nothing appears in the its console log) and the windows machine continuously throws Failed to create netty connection: java.net.SocketTimeOutException.

I have disabled the firewall in the ubuntu machine using the following command

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and then restarted the machine.

What would be the problem that makes the cluster not working between the Ubuntu machine and the other windows machines ?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis], a data mining technique. You probably meant [tag:load-balancing].

Answer (score 0):

The JBoss AS7 uses JGroups for the underlying group communication to discover cluster members and to from the cluster.

If you are running the server with the profile full-ha, the messaging system also forms a cluster. HornetQ is the default message provider in JBoss AS7. But HornetQ does  not use Jgroups for server discovering. It is completly independent. HornetQ uses Netty and in the default configuration UDP multicast to broadcast server connection settings.

Because you are using for JGroups TCPPing, I assume the server are maybe not in the same UDP multicast group.

Comment: `HornetQ uses Netty and in the default configuration UDP multicast to broadcast server connection settings` Where can I find this information in the Jboss Docs or HornetQ Docs?  Also, `I assume the server are maybe not in the same UDP multicast group` If this is the case how could I set the two servers to be in the same UDP multicast group?

Comment: I have checked the configuration of the three machines and the three Jboss instances are configured to use the same broadcast-group, the same host, and the same port. (Actually this is the default configuration I did not change any thing rather than the noted sections in the question above)

Comment: Here you will find the documentation of the server discovery section: http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html/clusters.html#clusters.server-discovery